# Windows reboots randomly on battery, linux OK

Tags: windows, linux, crash, power, reboot

About a week ago, the Windows partition on my laptop started rebooting randomly. No BSOD, nothing in event logs besides a kernel-power failure. I could still use linux (LuninuxOS) fine, and windows would work flawlessly if I had it plugged in. There are two probable causes I can think of:

1. I replaced (upgraded) the ram over Christmas to 8GB (Max supported by my laptop model). I have had no issues up until a week ago. I tried running memtest86+ and it only made it about 46% of the way through the test before adding errors every tick (I'm serious, I woke up and it had 120,000+ errors and climbing). I'm not sure if this is accurate, because I have had no slowdowns, no freezes, no problems in either windows or Linux since the upgrade, with the exception of this new development.
2. I accidentally allowed the battery to drain. I discovered that the power brick wasn't connected completely, and the battery drained over the course of a week. Upon rebooting, windows complained about some device not being available. After using linux for a week or so, I tried windows again and it worked fine, but was rebooting itself randomly on battery power. (See [this](http://techwiz24.tumblr.com/post/40790436482/sometimes-its-the-simple-things) blog post for details on the power issue)

Any suggestions? When I get time this weekend, I'll try re-installing windows, but I'd rather not if I can help it, because my internet connection isn't the fastest, and there's a lot of stuff I'd have to re-download to install.

Comment: memtest-86 shows memory errors.  That is almost certainly the problem.  Replace the RAM and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Agreed. There should be no errors at all.  Note that Windows might allocate memory in a different way or than Linux does. Which would explain why one OS is more likely to trigger the problem.